# Difference between use of sleep thread and refresh page in php as server event source

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, server-sent-events

I have built a chat application using server sent events .But sse are not supported across all browsers.I was planning to use long polling ajax for polling source page for browser which do not support sse.

What the server page does is check db for new messages and output it using echo statement.

By refreshing page every X seconds using `header("refresh: X;");`
I saw another approach by which the

```
while(1){

    echo statemenst....
    echo statemenst....

    sleep(5);
    }
```

**So my question is:** If I sent ajax request with a very large waiting time will it receive response If  header("refresh: X;"); is used .Or I need to use the infinite loop?.And if page refreshes will the requests to that page that are waiting for response get affected in someway ?

```
 function waitForMsg(){
        /* This requests the url "msgsrv.php"
        When it complete (or errors)*/
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "msgsrv.php",

            async: true, /* If set to non-async, browser shows page as "Loading.."*/
            cache: false,
            timeout:50000, /* Timeout in ms */

            success: function(data){ /* called when request to barge.php completes */
                addmsg("new", data); /* Add response to a .msg div (with the "new" class)*/
                setTimeout(
                    waitForMsg, /* Request next message */
                    1000 /* ..after 1 seconds */
                );
            },
            error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){
                addmsg("error", textStatus + " (" + errorThrown + ")");
                setTimeout(
                    waitForMsg, /* Try again after.. */
                    15000); /* milliseconds (15seconds) */
            }
        });
    };
```

Comment: If you're using sessions make sure to call `session_write_close` before you call `sleep()` .. otherwise you'll be blocking up all requests because the session file will still be blocked for writing.

Comment: And if page refreshes ajax callbacks are gone from the client (the javascript is all reloaded in the DOM) so you lose the response.

Comment: @developerwjk AJAX CALL IS MADE FROM ANOTHER PAGE TO SAY SERVER.PHP WHICH CONTAINS THE INFINITE LOOP OR PERIDICALLY REFRESHES SO HOW DOES REQUEST ARE HANDLED WHEN SERVER.PHP PERIODICALLY REFRESHES

Comment: The loop should only be semi-infinite. That is, it keeps looping until it finally returns the response, then the loop stops. So you don't want `while(1)` but like `while($responseNotReady)`